# How do I generate a php redirect with a dynamically generated url?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a php file that was given to me by a company that produces online coupons. The file is supposed to generate a dynamic url and then redirect you to that page. All they told me i needed to do was to create an echo call at the bottom. The $cpt is the only thing that should be dynamically generated in the url so this is what I have and it is not working properly.

```
 <?php
 //Generate cipher
 function EncodeCPT($pinCode, $offerCode, $shortKey, $longKey){
$decodeX = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!$%()*+,-.@;<=>?[]^_{|}~";
$encodeModulo = array_fill(0, 256, 0);

$vob[0] = $offerCode % 100;
$vob[1] = (($offerCode - $vob[0]) / 100) % 100;

for ($i = 0; $i < 61; $i++)
    $encodeModulo[substr($decodeX, $i, 1)] = $i;

$pinCode = strtolower($pinCode) . strval($offerCode);
if (strlen($pinCode) < 20){
    $pinCode .= ' couponsincproduction';
    $pinCode = substr($pinCode, 0, 20);
}

//$checkCode = "LC";
//$pinCode = "LC10";
//$offerCode = "115694";
//$shortKey = "6oigl3qf5e";
//$longKey = "Lm9A7w8tjpUCaoMidGFSYXrHZnyDRKhlTbk1Oz4f5QBsqveEWuxg6PNV2cJ3I";
$q = 0;
$j = strlen($pinCode);
$k = strlen($shortKey);
$s1 = $s2 = $s3 = null;

$cpt = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++){
    $s1 = $encodeModulo[substr($pinCode, $i, 1)];
    $s2 = 2 * $encodeModulo[substr($shortKey, $i % $k, 1)];
    $s3 = $vob[$i % 2];
    $q = ($q + $s1 + $s2 + $s3) % 61;
    $cpt .= substr($longKey, $q, 1);
}
return $cpt;
 }

 echo("http://bricks.coupons.com/enable.asp?0=115694&c=LC&p=LC10&" .$cpt);

 //echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=http://bricks.coupons.com /enable.asp?0=115694&c=LC&p=LC10&"($cpt)">';

 ?>
```

I have tried a couple things but nothing seems to be working. Does any one have any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to call the function EncodeCPT before you can use the variable returned by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you’ve defined the function `EncodeCPT` but you’ve never actually called it. You may think of function definitions as separate from other parts of your script. Any variable used inside a function (unless used with the `global` keyword) has only a local scope. Therefore, the variables `$pinCode`, `$offerCode`, `$shortKey`, `$longKey` and `$cpt` don’t even **exist** outside the scope of your function (if in doubt, check it with `isset`). To make them exist, you have to do something like the following:

```
/* Change these values if necessary */
$pinCode = "LC10";
$offerCode = "115694";
$shortKey = "6oigl3qf5e";
$longKey = "Lm9A7w8tjpUCaoMidGFSYXrHZnyDRKhlTbk1Oz4f5QBsqveEWuxg6PNV2cJ3I";
/* Do not change after this line */
$cpt = EncodeCPT($pinCode, $offerCode, $shortKey, $longKey);
$url = "http://bricks.coupons.com/enable.asp?0=115694&c=LC&p=LC10&".$cpt;
```

In spite of having identical names, `$pinCode`, `$offerCode`, `$shortKey`, `$longKey` and `$cpt` are global variables in the code above. To avoid confusion, you may use different names like `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$d`, `$e` or any valid variable names of your choice. For a clearer understanding of the matter, read more about [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) from the PHP manual.

Now comes the redirect part. If you want the script to redirect automatically:

```
header("location: $url");
```

On the other hand, if you want the user to click on a link for the redirect:

```
print("<a href=\"$url\">Click Here</a>");
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I meant to reply to this earlier but had to take care of another job. But this worked perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just use **`header()`**

Replace this

```
echo("http://bricks.coupons.com/enable.asp?0=115694&c=LC&p=LC10&" .$cpt);
```

with

```
$cpt = EncodeCPT("yourparameters");
header("location:http://bricks.coupons.com/enable.asp?0=115694&c=LC&p=LC10&$cpt");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the return value of the function EncodeCPT($pinCode, $offerCode, $shortKey, $longKey) 
You need to find where this function is called and do something like this:

$cpt = EncodeCPT(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,parameter4);

and at the end of the script you can then use $cpt, as mentioned by someone else.

header("location:http://bricks.coupons.com/enable.asp?0=115694&c=LC&p=LC10&$cpt");